# How can I avoid page breaks inside a table, with only inline styles and without CSS

Tags: html, page-break

I am working with an invoice editor that only accepts HTML and inline styles. The invoice editor will print to PDF when run.

I cannot find a way to avoid page breaks without using .CSS which it doesn't support. Any ideas besides manually typing break tags in and praying nobody has a long enough address or name to cause the invoice to break in a weird spot?

Comment: HTML doesn't force page breaks. Either the editor is doing this or when it's printed to PDF, the page break occurs because of the page layout.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `page-break-inside: avoid;` on any element as a inline style (a table, but also a section or a container DIV) to avoid that element to be split.